# Create a custom Calender scheduler in Adobe Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am trying to figure out how to design a calender scheduler in adobe flex. 
I have seen the `flexlib`swc, but it is not structured properly to use.
My idea is to get time in vertical as list and scheduler at right all in one panel.

Can anybody suggest what components I need use to design this custom component.

Please see the protoype screen below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll use core graphic components/spark to design this screen. The whole calender background will be a relative layout component like a group/canvas surrounded by the scroller. Each of the slot(blue color) will be extending a spark/uicomponent fills color with Graphics(circle rectangle etc,) so they'll be light weight. I've tried these, they work, but, it is a hectic process to get all things right, it may take 2 months - 3 months to get things done. If you find a open source project try digging the code.